# Is Application.DoEvents sending messages to a separate thread?

Tags: user-interface, windows-messages, event-loop

I've been trying to understand event loops (not going so well) in general and I've read that the windows messaging loop is single threaded. If it is, how can Application.DoEvents work? Doesn't an event loop process one message at a time and blocks while each message/event is being processed? Wouldn't the message event loop need to exist on a different thread from the one that is processing the message for Application.DoEvents to be possible? If there are separate threads, which one is it that we're calling the "main" thread? I'm sure I'm missing something very simple, I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spend the better part of the day figuring this out (if anything I say is wrong, please comment and let me know so I can correct it). I actually had to build an old Win32 application and create the message loop myself (I'm a pretty persistent SOB). So there is a function called WinMain that starts up the message loop which looks like this:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

The thing about GetMessage() is that it blocks until a message is available in the message queue. If you run a Windowed application and just sit there and look at the window (don't cause any actions that would post a message to the queue), the main thread (the thread the window was created on) is paused on GetMessage(). Now when a message does get posted, we enter the while loop (that is if the message is not quit which is 0). DispatchMessage() is the interesting function here. This function will eventually lead to (in .NET) events being raised by controls and execution of EventHandlers. What puzzled me is if the call stack is GetMessage()/DispatchMessage()/.../EventHandler, how is it possible for Application.DoEvents() to process messages? Well it's pretty simple. DoEvents in Win32 would look like this:

```
void DoEvents()
{
   MSG msg;
   HACCEL hAccelTable;

   hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_TESTWIN32));

   // Main message loop:
   while (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) != 0)
   {
       if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
       {
           TranslateMessage(&msg);
           DispatchMessage(&msg);
       }
   }
}
```

So DoEvents() actually starts up another loop to process events while inside the initial message loop's DispatchMessage()! **The key difference is that instead of using GetMessage() which blocks until there is a message in the queue, we use PeekMessage() which returns 0 and exists the loop when there are no longer any messages in the queue.**

So what if we click a button twice and in that button's EventHandler we have a DoEvents() call? The initial event loop will process the first click and fire the event. While the EventHandler is executing, at the DoEvents() call, the event will be fired a second time and the EventHandler will be entered again (sort of like a recursive call). That's scary!

So in the end, everything is happening in a single thread and DoEvents() actually blocks until all messages are processed then returns. Now I'm going to go to sleep for a couple days.